# Difference Between setData() and addData()

Tags: collection

What's the difference between `setData()` and `addData()`?
Is there a connection if I update a product or set a new one?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`setData` overrides the existing data and can receive as parameter either a pair key-value either an array.
if you set as parameters a pair key-value then `$_data[key]` becomes `value`. If you set as parameter an array `$_data` becomes that array overwriting what ever it contained previously.
Example:

```
$_data = array('k1' => 'v1' , 'k2' => 'v2');
```

calling `$obj->setData('k3','v3')` results in

```
$_data = array('k1' => 'v1' , 'k2' => 'v2', 'k3'=>'v3');
```

calling `$obj->setData(array('k3'=>'v3'))` results in

```
$_data = array('k3'=>'v3');
```

calling `$obj->setData('k2','v2000')` results in

```
$_data = array('k1' => 'v1' , 'k2' => 'v2000')
```

calling `$obj->setData(array('k2'=>'v2000'))` results in

```
$_data = array('k2'=>'v2000');
```

`addData` receives as parameter only an array and it merges that array with the existing data.

Example:

```
$_data = array('k1' => 'v1' , 'k2' => 'v2');
```

calling `$obj->addData(array('k3'=>'v3'))` results in

```
$_data = array('k1' => 'v1' , 'k2' => 'v2', 'k3'=>'v3');
```

but calling `$obj->addData(array('k2'=>'v2000'))` results in

```
$_data = array('k1' => 'v1' , 'k2' => 'v2000');
```

Comment: what happens when we do `$obj->setData('k2'=>'v2399393')` then? :-) (great if you add this specific point in your answer)

Comment: @RajeevKTomy. Done.

Comment: Sorry I can upvote you only once :-)

Comment: your update is different. You skipped above specified request. I asked `$obj->setData('k2'=>'v2399393')` and not `$obj->setData(array('k2'=>'v2000'))`

Comment: @RajeevKTomy. Is this a joke?

Comment: no sir.  I asked this. we have  `$_data = array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2')` then what happens if we do `$obj->setData('k2'=>'v2000')` . (means what happens if we set already existing value?)I think that is what the point your answer lags. Did you get my point now ?

Comment: Thanks @ marius. you answer is  more solid  then me.... up-vote from me

Comment: @RajeevKTomy. OK. Sorry. I read it wrong.

Comment: no problem at all :-)

Comment: It is also possible in Magento session @Marius

Comment: yes it's possible, but getData works a bit different from the session so be careful on how you use the date after setting it.

Answer (score 7):

**setData()**

function is `only set one field value on one call`. it can `set multiple field value using multiple call of setData function`.

**addData()** function is `set multiple field values using array with array key as field index.`

**Just Example:**

You want two field to set at object.

- field a>Value->X
- field b>Value->Y

If i using `setData()` then you need to do this type of works.need  For two field you  need call setData function two wise.

```
$ObVarien->setData('fieldA',$X);
$ObVarien->setData('fieldB',$Y);
```

But if i using `addData()` then you can  do this `array key as field name`

```
$Data=array('fieldA'=>$X,'fieldb'=>$Y)

$ObVarien->addData($Data)
```

**addData()** and **setData()** are two Library  `Varien_Object` class function.

addData() using  setData() at lib file for set field value using loop.

```
public function addData(array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $index=>$value) {
        $this->setData($index, $value);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: You can use `setData` to set more than one field with one call.

Comment: @Marius i  have check the lib class. and you answer more clear then me