# How to create new order magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, orders, sales-order

I can get information regarding orders using 3rd party API but when I want to save it into 3 tables, for **sales_flat_order** and **sales_flat_order_adress** the data has been saved and for **sales_flat_order_grid** I've gotten this error I think that I want to save the Parent_id in the entity_id as it should be same. But I don't know how.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`sales_flat_order_grid`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_GRID_ENTITY_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `sales_flat_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CA)' in D:\wamp\www\magento1.9\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228
```

this array that I want to save for 3 tables

```
Foreach($array as $value){
                    $array = array('status' => $value['status'],
                 'base_grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'increment_id' => $value['number'],
                 'base_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'customer_email' => $value['email'],
                 'customer_firstname' => $value['name'],
                 'customer_lastname' => $value['apellido'],
                 'global_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'order_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'store_name' => 'linio marketplace',
                 'created_at' => $value['created'],
                 'updated_at' => $value['created'],
                 'total_item_count' => $value['item']);
                  $modele = Mage::getModel('thorleif/order')->setData($array);
                  $modele->save();
                 $id = $modele->getId();
                 $array = array(
                 'parent_id' => $id,
                 'region' => $value['region'],
                 'postcode' => $value['zip'],
                 'street' => $value['address'].'.'.$value['country'],
                 'city' => $value['city'],
                 'email' => $value['email'],
                 'telephone' => $value['tel'],
                 'firstname' => $value['name'],
                 'lastname' => $value['apellido'],
                 'address_type' => 'shipping');
                  $modele = Mage::getModel('thorleif/address')->setData($array);
                  $modele->save();
                  $array = array(
                 'parent_id' => $id,
                 'status' => $value['status'],
                 'base_grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'grand_total' => $value['price'],
                 'increment_id' => $value['number'],
                 'base_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'shipping_name' => $value['name'],
                 'global_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'order_currency_code' => 'MXN',
                 'store_name' => 'linio marketplace',
                 'created_at' => $value['created'],
                 'updated_at' => $value['created']);
                  $modele = Mage::getModel('thorleif/grid')->setData($array);
                  $modele->save();
                 }
```

Comment: Is it for us to guess line 46 ?

Comment: I have this in line 46  `if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != 'free') {
            return $this;
        }`

Comment: Please put your full code and the name of each one

Comment: this the principle code. I get the external data using http://input and I put each value into variable. so I use the model for order to save those data as new order using setdata or adddata method.

Comment: Take a look at these two methods on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877767/create-order-programmatically-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to check if you get well your paiement method code:

```
$paymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();

foreach($paymentMethods as $paymentMethod) {
    echo $paymentMethod->getCode();
}
```

**Edit:**

Check also this one and look if you get the payment method code :

```
$order->getPayment->getMethodInstance()->getData()
```

If you get your payment method :

```
$order->getPayment()->getMethod();
```

You can follow this [inchoo tuto](http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/) to create an order programmatically

Comment: my payment value is like this CashOnDelivery_Payment so I don't know if this is the issue?

Comment: Please look my update.

Comment: I've use it this line to test it and it works updating information `$modele = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(194);` but what I need to do is to create a new row, but using addData doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what you mean by create new row? if you want to archieve some information use `setData()` and `getData()`, if you want to use an array use `addData()` check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/62539/48355

Comment: What I need to do is to create new order in table "sales_flat_order" using the code before putting each value in the attribute and save all the values I got.

Comment: look my update again please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61940/discussion-between-javatodev-and-prince).

Comment: I think the url you sent could help. I've thought that it would be easy to create an order using module as I create or get product catalogs.

Comment: I've added an answer I hope is clear to understand what I've implemented and if you have any observation?

Answer (score 0):

It's work to me using the insertion like this for **sales_flat_order_grid**

```
$entity_id =1; 
$entity_type_id =4; 
$attribute_id = 92;
$value = 'red'; 
$store_id  =1;
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeAdapter   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('some_table_name');
$query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES ($entity_id, $entity_type_id, $attribute_id, $value, $store_id);";
$writeAdapter->query($query);
```